# How to get a UITableViewCell change its background color by tapping a UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to make a UIBarButtonItem in the right-corner of my tableView in order to highlight and un-highlight a cell when pressed.

In less words, when users press the button, a range of cells will change their background color from white to yellow.

I'm failing to make that though, because every time i press that button the app crashes.

Here's the code i'm using to create the button:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIBarButtonItem *barButton;
    barButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"high.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(colorCells:)] autorelease];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton; 
}
```

And here to make it highlight a range of cells:

```
- (void) colorCells:(id)sender
{
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    NSString *cellValue = cell.textLabel.text; 
    if ([cellValue isEqual: @"textTheCellShouldBeEqualTo"]){ 
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:251/255.0f green:255/255.0f blue:192/255.0f alpha:1]; ; 
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hot.png"];

    } 
    else { 
        cell.imageView.image = nil;
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    } 
}
```

Where am i failing? It's supposed to work fine. Or? Am i missing something? The view is a UITableViewController.

**EDIT**

I modified my code like so:

```
- (void) colorCells:(id)sender{
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    NSInteger nSections = [self.tableView numberOfSections];
    for (int j=0; j<nSections; j++) {
        NSInteger nRows = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:j];
        for (int i=0; i<nRows; i++) {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:j];
            cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        }
        NSString *cellValue = cell.textLabel.text; 
        if ([cellValue isEqual: @"textTheCellShouldBeEqualTo"] ){ 
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:251/255.0f green:255/255.0f blue:192/255.0f alpha:1]; ; 
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hot.png"];

        } 
        else { 
            cell.imageView.image = nil;
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        } 
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    }
}
```

Now it doesn't crash, but it doesn't color the background too. Any ideas?

Comment: try adding [self.tableView beginUpdates]; and [self.tableView endUpdates]; at the end

Comment: Still can't color the selected cell. :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basing the background color off of the text in a cell seems incredibly fragile. What determines that a cell should be highlighted? Does it change? Surely, the color of the background corresponds to a specific property of the objects in your data source. A more robust approach would be to use an `NSMutableIndexSet` property on your class to track a set of row indexes require highlighting upon tapping the bar button.

Consider this example. I'm assuming that `rowsToHighlight` is an instance of `NSMutableIndexSet` declared in your class and that it has been populated with the indexes of rows that require highlighting. We're going to implement `-tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` to adjust the background color of the cell depending if the provided index path is a member of `rowsToHighlight`.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([self.rowsToHighlight containsIndex:indexPath.row])
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    }
}
```

Then in the method that is fired by your bar button, just do an empty update block to get the table to reload with animation.

```
- (void)colorCells:(id)sender
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: Well, thanks for your answer. I got few questions though. How can NSMutableIndexSet know which cells i want to higlight, due i want highlight only the cells that contains a specific name in a specific section (that it may be mutable when i add rows and sort them)? I wanted to make a button to handle the background color: when i tap on it, the cell background should be yellow, when i tap on it again it should be again white.

Comment: That's my point. What kind of objects are you using to populate your table view? This would be incredibly simple if it was some `NSObject` subclass that exposed a `BOOL` that indicates whether a cell should be highlighted. The object itself could encapsulate all of the logic required to determine if it should be highlighted. Comparing strings in your table view data source methods is clunky at best.

Comment: I'm using `NSArray` & `NSDictionary` to populate my tV. Sorry if i don't get the point, but I'm pretty new to this dev world, so what you have just wrote may result a bit confusing for me!

Comment: And the text you're putting in the cell is the *only* way to differentiate whether it should be highlighted or not?

Comment: I think so, due when i add rows (by adding objects into the array), they're being sorted by name, and due i'm handling 2 localizations, that's the only way i know

Comment: Have you considered that this approach is going to fail in alternate languages because you're comparing it to a hardcoded english string?

Comment: Nope, i did not, basically because my app is made of 2 languages, and i'm not planning to put any additional language

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6627/discussion-between-mark-adams-and-phillip)

Answer (score 0):

Your cells won't redraw unless you tell the table view which contains them to reload them. You can do this with one of several methods. You may consider `[someTableView reloadData]` or [one of these methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW9).

Also, your cell object is not the one in your table view. You might consider this:

```
- (void) colorCells:(id)sender
{
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    //grab a cell
    cell = [self  tableView:self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:someRow inSection:someSection]];
    NSString *cellValue = cell.textLabel.text; 
    if ([cellValue isEqual: @"textTheCellShouldBeEqualTo"]){ 
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:251/255.0f green:255/255.0f blue:192/255.0f alpha:1]; ; 
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hot.png"];

    } 
    else { 
        cell.imageView.image = nil;
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    } 

   //perhaps you need to reload the table as well
   [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: How does `cellForRowAtIndexPath` works if i have 3 separate arrays, each one containing a variable number of cells? (i.e. `FirstArray` = 13 objects, `SecondArray` = 45 objects, `ThirdArray` = 20 objects) Which path should i take?

Comment: Are you showing one array at a time in the table, or is each array part of the table? The index path just tells the table's delegate which row and which section to give you a table for.

Comment: Nope, each array is part of the table. I have 3 sections, where the first belongs to `FirstArray` , below, the second sections belongs to `SecondArray` and the third belongs to `ThirdArray`. What the `indexPath` should be then?

Comment: Use `[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:inSection:]` to set the index path for the section and row of the cell you want.

Comment: Whatever method i try i get this warning: `warning: instance method '-cellForRowAtIndexPath:' not found (return type defaults to 'id') `

Comment: It's a table view delegate method. `[self tableView:self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];`

Comment: Still getting the crash. I edited again the code adding  `- (void) colorCells:(id)sender atIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath`  , but i get still crashes. Also, if i use your code, i can't get the cells background change!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6629/discussion-between-moshe-and-phillip)